# Adjective to describe someone who values and nurtures their interpersonal relationships

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to describe someone who values their interpersonal relationships with family, friends and colleagues, and who puts time and effort into developing and nurturing those relationships?

For example, if I was describing someone's personal qualities, I might describe them as being smart, humble, kind, passionate and X; where X is the adjective I'm looking for.

Comment: Your own term, *nurturing*, works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [**Warm-hearted**](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=warm%20definition&ie=&oe=#dobs=warm-hearted)
>   adjective: warm-hearted; adjective: warmhearted
>   sympathetic and kind.
>   "a warm-hearted, affectionate girl"
>   synonyms:
>   kind, warm, kind-hearted, kindly, soft-hearted, good-hearted, big-hearted, tender-hearted, tender, loving, caring, feeling, unselfish, selfless, benevolent, humane, good-natured, affectionate; More
>   gentle, mild, indulgent, friendly, open, sympathetic, understanding, compassionate, charitable, generous, magnanimous 
>   "they are perhaps the most generous, warm-hearted people in the universe"
>   antonyms:
>   unkind, unfriendly

Also

> [**Caring**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/caring)
>   adjective
>   If someone is caring, they are affectionate, helpful, and sympathetic. 
>   He is a lovely boy, very gentle and caring.
>   ...a loving, caring husband.

A combination of the two is  "Warm and caring"

Answer (score 7):

People who are introverted, and who have fewer friends, can still be fiercely loyal to the friends they do have, valuing and nurturing them. So, it's not really about quantity (as garrulousness might imply) but quality.

Therefore, I think a good adjective here is [**committed**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/committed):

> having made a pledge or commitment to someone (such as a romantic partner) or something (such as a cause) · *committed* partners · a *committed* parent/teacher  strongly *committed* to the fight for equal rights ; also : characterized by such a pledge or commitment · two people in a *committed* relationship

Answer (score 6):

***[Sociable:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sociable)***

> inclined by nature to companionship with others of the same species.
>
> marked by or conducive to friendliness or pleasant social relations.

(M-W)

Also

[Extrovert](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/extrovert):

> an energetic happy person who enjoys being with other people:
> *Most sales people are extroverts.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

[***Gregarious***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gregarious)

> fond of the company of others; sociable.

Answer (score -2):

A person who displays the characteristics you listed above could be described as conscientious.